# How to schedule custom task through c#

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I am using [Task Scheduler](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/) for scheduling my task in c# application. I think i got the basic understanding of this library.

But now i stuck in a place where i want to create a custom action which will execute on the set schedule.Like the [built-in action](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ActionSamples&referringTitle=Documentation) i.e *EmailAction* ( Which will send mail on set schedule ), *ShowMessageAction* ( Which will show alert message on set schedule ), i want to create an action which will run my c# code and that code will save some data to my database.

What I tried yet is: I created a class *CustomAction* which inherits *Action*, like :

```
public class NewAction : Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.Action
{
    public override string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Id;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Id = value;
        }
    }

    public NewAction()
    {
    }
}
```

And here is my task scheduler code :

```
    ..  
    ... 
    // Get the service on the local machine
    using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
    {
        // Create a new task definition and assign properties
        TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
        td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";

        // Create a trigger that will fire the task at this time every other day
        TimeTrigger tt = new TimeTrigger();

        tt.StartBoundary = DateTime.Today + TimeSpan.FromHours(19) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        tt.EndBoundary = DateTime.Today + TimeSpan.FromHours(19) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
        tt.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

        td.Triggers.Add(tt);

        // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
        td.Actions.Add(new NewAction());   <==========================

        // Register the task in the root folder
        ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Test", td);

        // Remove the task we just created
        //ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask("Test");
    }
    ...
    ....
```

On the line (pointed by arrow) i am getting the exception :

> value does not fall within the expected range task scheduler

I am not sure what i am trying to achieve is even possible or not, if it is possible than please guid me on the correct direction?

Comment: You can't just have it execute random actions. There are only 4 actions available. To run custom code execute a process with the exec action that will do whatever code you want.

Answer (score 1):

According my understanding of your question. I had implemented same thing, but I had used "Quartz" Scheduler instead of "Task Scheduler". It is very easy to implement. May be you can also try with this.

To reference:
http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/

Please correct me if I am wrong.